# Wget gives correct results when stdout and wrong results when saving to file

Tags: bash, file, pipe, stdout, io-redirection

Im trying to get some data about films from idmb database.

Using command

```
wget -O - https://datasets.imdbws.com/title.basics.tsv.gz | gunzip | head -n 10 | tail  -n 5| tr "\t" ","
```

it instantly gives me 5 lines of imdb data (correct), however when I try to write that output to file

```
wget -O data.txt https://datasets.imdbws.com/title.basics.tsv.gz | gunzip | head -n 10 | tail  -n 5| tr "\t" ","
```

it tries to download entire database which ends up with unreadable data.txt. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Append to your first command: `> data.txt`

Comment: The `-O` option tells `wget` to send its output directly to that file, rather than passing it to the rest of the pipeline for processing. You want the output from `tr` put in a file, not the output from `wget`.